# Does $2y^2=x^4-17$ have solution in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Does $2y^2=x^4-17$ have solution in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ ?

It is well known that the equation has no solution in $\Bbb{Q}$, but I wonder does that holds for number field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

I calculated its Tate-Shafarevich group and proved the equation has solution in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, but having difficulty finding exactly what the solution is.

If it has rational points, results only or **computer calculation** is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my mistake, Tate-Shafarevich group was not trivial and I (may) proved this has no solution by using Brauer-Manin obstruction.So I can close this question but some elementary answer may come, so I leave this question.

Comment: $\sqrt{-3}$ is a root of $x^2+3$ in $\overline {\Bbb{Q}}$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is a minimal field which contains both $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ in $\overline {\Bbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Have you tried just running a simulation? If any solutions exist, I can’t imagine them being that large.

Comment: @Eric That's usually not the case with elliptic curves

Comment: @Eric If there are rational points, it should be very large, I think.

Comment: Considering that your curve does not have a rational point, your claim that you computed sha is dubious (do you mean Sha of the Jacobian?). In any case, one can show that $C$ represents an element of the $2$-torsion in $\rm{Sha}(\rm{Jac}(C))$ using the Cassels-Tate pairing. Do a $2$-descent and find another element of $\rm{Sel}^2$ which you think should work then pair them together

Comment: I mean, smooth compactification of projective closure of affine curves $2y^2=x^4-17$(Let call the smooth compactification $C$) is an element of $Sha(J(C))$. As I added to $P.S$ before, my calculation at first was wrong and She is not trivial.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the method you mentioned in your comment and post it in the answer form?

Comment: There are already nice examples e.g., in the Magma handbook, feel free to work through the details and answer your own question below http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1515